# Example for quasi-commuting matrices

Tags: noncommutative-algebra

I can not find example of 2 matrices that quasi commute; $[A,B]=AB−BA = c I$, where $c$ is a scalar not equal to $0$ and $I$ is the identity matrix. As far as I know there is no 2x2 matrices that satisfy the quasi commutative property. Any help for the 3x3 matrices?

Comment: You need characteristic $p\mid n$ for nontrivial examples.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown; field characteristic p is 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}$$
As pointed out in the comments, there are no finite-dimensional examples over a field of characteristic $0$, since
$$0=\Tr\,[A,B]=c\Tr I=cn$$
which implies $c=0$ if $n$ is a nonzerodivisor.

For an infinite-dimensional example, consider the operators
$$\begin{align}
D &: \mathbb{Q}[x]\to\mathbb{Q}[x] & Dp(x)&=p'(x)\\
X &: \mathbb{Q}[x]\to\mathbb{Q}[x] & Xp(x)&=x\cdot p(x)\text{.}
\end{align}$$
on the ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ of univariate polynomials with coefficients from $\mathbb{Q}$. Since $\mathbb{Q}[x]\cong \mathbb{Q}^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$ *qua* $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces (pick the monomial basis), with respect to this isomorphism $D$ and $X$ admit infinite-dimensional matrix representations. Furthermore, 
$$DX-XD=I\text{.}$$